# Threading continuations confusion?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, continuations

I have a simple continuation type (similar to the `Free` monad):

```
data C m a = C {runC :: (a -> m a) -> m a}

toBeContinued :: Int -> C Maybe Int
toBeContinued i = C $ \todo -> todo i

continuing :: Int -> Maybe Int
continuing i = Just 100
```

I'm then looking to create two interleaved threads of these suspended continuations, all of which to be executed using the same continuing function:

```
data PoorMans m a = Atomic (m (PoorMans m a)) | Done a

instance Monad m => Monad (PoorMans m) where
  (>>=) (Atomic m) f = Atomic $ (liftM (>>= f) m)
  (>>=) (Done m) f = f m
  return  = Done

atomic :: Monad m => m a -> PoorMans m a
atomic m = Atomic $ liftM Done m

runThread :: Monad m => m a -> PoorMans m a
runThread (Atomic m) = m >>= runThread
runThread (Done m) = return m

interleave :: Monad m => PoorMans m a -> PoorMans m a -> PoorMans m a
interleave (Atomic m1) (Atomic m2) = do
    n1 <- m1
    n2 <- m2
    interleave n1 n2
interleave (Done _) m2 = m2
interleave m1 (Done _) = m1
```

I'm now trying to create two threads of suspended operations, which I can then pass to `interleave` then into `runThread` with a continuation operation to be applied to all suspended operations:

```
createSuspendedOperations :: Int -> PoorMans (C Maybe) Int
createSuspendedOperations i = atomic $ toBeContinued 12
```

Error:

```
 No instance for (Monad (C Maybe))
    arising from a use of ‘atomic’
```

I understand that I must make `C` an instance of `Monad` as `atomic` is bound by `Monad m =>`:

```
 instance Monad m => Monad (C m) where
```

However here I am stuck as to how to define the behaviors of `>>=` and `return` for `C m a`?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way this is a monad, because `a` is an invariant parameter of `C m a`. ([Here is an FPComplete post about variance.](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/11/covariance-contravariance))

You might want to take a look at the ["continuation monad" in transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:ContT).